# Error in code for identifying most spoke language using default world database of mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, join

I was writing a code in mysql using the standard database of world to figure populate a list of countries along with the language most commonly spoken. The table I am using is the standard  tables within world - city, country and countrylanguage. The output is satisfactory for most part, however, for Japan, the code gives me an incorrect value (most spoke language should be Japanese (99.1%), however my code gives me Ainu (0%). Not sure where I am going wrong. Can someone help?

```sql
use world; 
select 
country.name as country, 
city.countrycode, 
count(city.name) as cities, 
country.population, 
countrylanguage.language, 
percentage  
from 
city  
inner join 
country  on city.countrycode=country.code  
inner join 
countrylanguage  on country.code=countrylanguage.countrycode    
where countrylanguage.percentage in  
(select max(percentage)         
from countrylanguage         
group by countrycode) 
group by country.name 
order by country.population desc ;
```

This is my output -

```
China CHN 363 1277558000 Chinese 92.0 
India IND 341 1013662000 Hindi 39.9 
United States USA 274 278357000 English 86.2 
Indonesia IDN 85 212107000 Javanese 39.4 
Brazil BRA 250 170115000 Portuguese 97.5 
Pakistan PAK 59 156483000 Punjabi 48.2 
Russian Federation RUS 189 146934000 Russian 86.6 
Bangladesh BGD 24 129155000 Bengali 97.7 
Japan JPN 496 126714000 Ainu 0.0 
Nigeria NGA 192 111506000 Hausa 21.1 
Mexico MEX 173 98881000 Spanish 92.1 
Germany DEU 93 82164700 German 91.3 
Vietnam VNM 22 79832000 Vietnamese 86.8 
Philippines PHL 136 75967000 Pilipino 29.3
```

Comment: What is the *standard database of world* - please provide relevant links

Comment: ok, there goes - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/world-setup-installation.html

Comment: The query is incorrect (incomplete grouping). Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: This is my output
China CHN 363 1277558000 Chinese 92.0
India IND 341 1013662000 Hindi 39.9
United States USA 274 278357000 English 86.2
Indonesia IDN 85 212107000 Javanese 39.4
Brazil BRA 250 170115000 Portuguese 97.5
Pakistan PAK 59 156483000 Punjabi 48.2
Russian Federation RUS 189 146934000 Russian 86.6
Bangladesh BGD 24 129155000 Bengali 97.7
**Japan JPN 496 126714000 Ainu 0.0**
Nigeria NGA 192 111506000 Hausa 21.1
Mexico MEX 173 98881000 Spanish 92.1
Germany DEU 93 82164700 German 91.3
Vietnam VNM 22 79832000 Vietnamese 86.8
Philippines PHL 136 75967000 Pilipino 29.3